# Sort by 2 values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table with columns [ID, Name, Type] where the Type column has values (1 OR 2). I want to write a select query with a limit so that when the limit is 10, the query should get 8 records with (Type=1) + 2 records (Type=2). The table has around 70k records with (Type=1) and 20k records with (Type=2)

Also, I need the page limit to 10 so the LIMIT 10 is needed as the page results should run with php pagination.

```
(SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Type=1 
LIMIT 8
) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Type=2 
LIMIT 2) 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: At first glance your query looks correct, What is your question? (you can omit the last `LIMIT 10`, and maybe add back-quotes around `Type`)

Comment: You can use UNION instead of UNION ALL. As @Pepper suggested, there is no need for LIMIT 10.

Comment: `ID, Name, Type` and then `ORDER BY title`. Is there a field `title` ?

Comment: I'd stick with `UNION ALL` because the set of `Type=1` might have dups within it; same with `Type=2`. I'd also recommend ordering each of the queries if predictable results are needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The limit 10 is needed because I need the results with PHP pagination and each page should have (8 records from type1) and (2 records from type2)

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Type` = 1 LIMIT 8 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Type` = 2 LIMIT 2
ORDER BY `title` ASC
```

you haven't needed to set the first selection in clips and your last LIMIT 10 is useless too because you have a LIMIT count of 10.

To understand:

`table` and `type` are SQL statements so if you named attributes like statemants you should use the single backquote `` ` `` for Selections, Inserts, Updates and Deletes.

> The MySQL UNION ALL operator is used to combine the result sets of 2
>   or more SELECT statements. It returns all rows from the query and it
>   does not remove duplicate rows between the various SELECT statements.
>   Each SELECT statement within the MySQL UNION ALL operator must have
>   the same number of fields in the result sets with similar data types.

Comment: The limit 10 is needed because I need the results with PHP pagination and each page should have (8 records from type1) and (2 records from type2). I will try this and will update here